# How to render HTML to a variable

Tags: twig

I need to render a list of HTML elements with content and put it into a variable. How can I do this efficient in twig?

e.g. I need to render the post tracking URLs from an order which can have several shippings / parcels.

```
{% for delivery in order.deliveries %} 
{% for trackingCode in delivery.getTrackingCodes() %}
    <a href="{{ delivery.shippingMethod.trackingUrl|replace({"%s":trackingCode}|raw) }}">{{ trackingCode }}</a><br/>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of printing this directly into the output I like first to put this rendered output into a variable like

```
 {% set output = ... %}
 ...
 {{ output }}
```

How can I do this in twig?

Comment: At what point in your code are wanting to render it to the variable? Inside the second For loop? And do you need to access it outside of the 1st For loop?

Comment: I need to have the output for both for loops, means when everything has been processed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I found a better more efficient way

you can use `{% set var %}` with `{% endset %}` as a whole output block. Means the whole output will be set to the variable. This makes the life much easier and readable.
e.g.

```
{% set trackingText %}
    {% for delivery in order.deliveries %} 
    {% for trackingCode in delivery.getTrackingCodes() %}
    <a href="{{ delivery.shippingMethod.trackingUrl|replace({"%s":trackingCode}|raw) }}">{{ trackingCode }}</a><br/>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endset %}
...
{% if trackingText|trim is not empty %} 
    You can track the delivery by using the following URL:<br/>
    {{ trackingText }}
    <br/>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the concatenate the html to the `output` variable. Keep in mind you'll need to define to the variable outside the `for`-loop in order to use it outside the loop.

```html
{% set foo = '' %}

{% for i in 1..10 %}
    {% set foo = foo ~ '<a href="#">'~i~'</a>' %}
{% endfor %}

{{ foo|raw }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/cw6wjc)

Comment: Thank you, is there no other efficient way? i.e. in PHP you could do a redirect of the output into a variable.